What do you call the front end of a pioneer’s wagon?
The part where the driver, holding the reins would sit, with another person by his side.

Picture please. There are a number of different styles of wagon of different sizes and complexities: some have a separate cab on the front, some have a single chassis but the cover doesn't go the full length, while others have the cover over the whole wagon and the driver sticking out of the end of the cover. Depending on the complexity, there may be a raised seat with back, suspension, etc, maybe just a box to sit on, or maybe nothing.

Do you mean the "seat"?

Covered Wagon Parts images | Horse drawn wagon, Farm wagons

This labelled image calls it a "seat" too. Google images has several other diagrams without naming it, perhaps because they thought it too obvious.

I think that this illustration, and the one @WeatherVane points us at, shows that the seat is at the front of the wagon.  I think, but have no nicely-drawn images to support my assertion, that the front of the wagon is called, simply, the front.  And I'll continue to think this until someone digs out an authoritative-ish diagram which labels that part some other way.  You know, like a diagram of a ship might label the front the bow.
